# Is ASP.NET Core 2.0 the technology which is implemented in both frameworks (.Net Framework and .NET Core)?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to create an ASP.NET Core MVC 2 web application which I could host on Linux and Windows (i.e. in both OS). So, I am to use .Net Core. But when I create new ASP.NET Core MVC 2 web application I see two comboboxes. At first I am to select either .NET Frmework or .NET Core. The second combobox contains only ASP.NET Core 2.0.

[image]

**Q1:**
Does it mean that *ASP.NET Core 2.0* is *technology* which is implemented in both frameworks (.Net Framework and .NET Core)?

It is impossible to switch .Net Framework to .NET Core for such project later. I could use .NET Core but [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service) Microsoft writes that I am to use .NET Framework if I want to use Windows Service...

I want to use [Nginx for Windows](https://nginx.ru/en/download.html) on my computer (instead of IIS) - it is interesting for me to try it. :) [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?tabs=aspnetcore2x) Microsoft describes how to host ASP.NET Core web application on Linux with NGinx. At the article the *Create the service file* topic exists. But it is for Linux... So, if I want to host my ASP.NET Core MVC 2 web application on Nginx in Windows then I am forced to use Windows Services (look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service)). But in the *[Host an ASP.NET Core app in a Windows Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service)* article Microsoft writes that I am to use .NET Framework instead of .NET Core...

**Q2**
Does it mean that I can't the same project use for build my web application for Linux and Windows (for Windows Service)? Does it mean that for my goal I am to create two project: for .NET Framework and for .NET Core and to share the code sources for both projects?

[image]

Comment: It says the recommended way to run an ASP.NET Core 2.0 app on Windows without IIS is to do it as a Windows Service. That doesn't mean it's the only way. If it's just for dev purposes, you could self host it, or front it with Nginx. .NET Core is cross platform. .NET Framework is only for Windows (unless you count Mono). ASP.NET Core 2.0 runs on either .NET Core or .NET Framework.

Comment: @mason, Of course I can to launch `dotnet myApp.dll` but at this case the console window is visible. It is not the same that I want.

Comment: Are you wanting to run it on Windows as a production service? Or just for development or experimentation purposes?

Comment: Both cases are interesting for me.

Comment: As Microsoft says, if you want to run it on Windows in production, you should use IIS.

Answer (score -1):

Q1

> Does it mean that ASP.NET Core 2.0 is technology which is implemented
>   in both frameworks (.Net Framework and .NET Core)?

.NET Core 2.0 and .NET Framework 4.6.1 are both implementations of .NET Standard 2.0. What this means is that they can both do the same things, and work mostly the same, but .NET Framework contains some Windows only libraries (System libraries such as Windows Forms) that mean it can only run on Windows. .Net Core programs can run on Windows, Linux and MacOS.

> It is impossible to switch .Net Framework to .NET Core for such
>   project later. I could use .NET Core but here Microsoft writes that I
>   am to use .NET Framework if I want to use Windows Service...

While this is technically possible, you really want to avoid it. It's a huge headache, and usually breaks a lot of your code, with missing dependancies etc.

> I want to use Nginx for Windows on my computer (instead of IIS) - it
>   is interesting for me to try it. :) Here Microsoft describes how to
>   host ASP.NET Core web application on Linux with NGinx. At the article
>   the Create the service file topic exists. But it is for Linux... So,
>   if I want to host my ASP.NET Core MVC 2 web application on Nginx in
>   Windows then I am forced to use Windows Services (look here). But in
>   the Host an ASP.NET Core app in a Windows Service article Microsoft
>   writes that I am to use .NET Framework instead of .NET Core...

I haven't personally used NGinx for Windows, but it looks as though they want you to set the target version for your NET Core app to NET Framework for the purposes of their example. Since .NET Core doesn't have the references to System specific libraries, you can easily change target to NET Framework. This doesn't make it a NET Framework project, it just changes the runtime against which Visual Studio will build it.

Q2

> Does it mean that I can't the same project use for build my web
>   application for Linux and Windows (for Windows Service)? Does it mean
>   that for my goal I am to create two project: for .NET Framework and
>   for .NET Core and to share the code sources for both projects?

You can absolutely use the same application for both platforms, however it'll be a little different to how you're used to it. Since .NET Core is platform agnostic, Visual Studio won't generate an exe for you, it'll just generate dll files. You then use the dotnet command at the command line to start the program, e.g.

```
dotnet helloWorld.dll
```

This is how you run the program on any OS, provided you have the .NET Core runtime installed (There are plenty of guides on how to do this online).

Hope I've answered everything clearly :)

Comment: For Q1, due to the RC1 release announcement (.NET Core 2.0 only build), there was information showing that ASP.NET Core 2.0 would miss certain features if running on .NET Framework. I think that still applies today.

Comment: .NET Framework is not "platform agnostic". You also seem to have confused .NET Core with ASP.NET Core. You really need to be careful how you word your answer, as you'll just end up spreading more confusion.